# Path of an electron around a nucleus

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbitals

I have just started reading about quantum mechanics and i stumbled upon this silly question - Quantum mechanical model of an atom  says that path of an electron around the nucleus is uncertain. Then how can we be sure that it's not circular?

Comment: It's not anything. That's how we know it isn't circular

Comment: It’s not a uncertain path. It can’t be described as a path *at all*.

Answer (score 3):

A "path of an electron around the nucleus" does not exist. There is no "motion" of the electron. Electron state, represented by a ket vector in the Hilbert space, can be stationary or nonstationary, in any case, there is no trajectory corresponding to this state.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the ground, state of the hydrogen atom. It has zero angular momentum so we can be sure that in this case the motion is not circular.

In quantum mechanics the concept of electron orbit is replaced by the concept of atomic orbital or more general, wave function. There are  distributions of potential energy, kinetic energy, momentum. Once you know the wave function you know these distributions and you can predict the outcome of experiments in a statistical sense.